# Выделение двух ячеек таблицы, и формирование ссылки

Tags: jquery, массивы, ссылки

Пишу сейчас скрипт на PHP, но очень нужно к нему приделать одну вещь.

На странице есть таблица, состоящая из двух столбцов, данные в этих столбцах одинаковые, пользователь кликает на ячейку в первой колонке, потом на ячейку во второй колонке. Скрипт берет данные из этих ячеек и формирует ссылку, на которую и отправляет пользователя.

Рабочий пример такого можно увидеть на сайтах мониторингах обменников, к примеру bestchange.ru, таблица с валютами справа.

Вопрос как такое реализировать? может есть где-то инструкции, примеры? Пробовал искать сам, но ничего не нашел, наверное неправильно запросы формирую...

Спасибо, ну судя по примеру разобрался немного, обрабатывать курсы и тому подобное мне не нужно.

Мне нужно более просто. Есть таблица:

```
<tr id="ti1">
<td id="dlc1" id="dlc1"><a href="#">WMZ</a></td>
<td id="drc1" id="dlc1"><a href="#">WMZ</a></td>
</tr>

<tr id="ti2">
<td class="lc" id="dlc2"><a href="#">WMR</a></td>
<td class="rc" id="drc2"><a href="#">WMR</a></td>
</tr>
```

Клик по одной ячейке, клик по второй ячейке, скрипт берет например параметр id из этих ячеек, и формирует ссылку [http://сайт.ru/](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru/)**dlc1**-to-**dlc2**.html и отправляет пользователя по этой ссылке (перенаправление).

Ну или как сделать по другому?
В каждую ячейку вставляю скрытый `checkbox` или `radio` с нужные мне значениями при клике  на вторую ячейку, скрипт отправляет значение из первой колонки и второй PHP скрипту, ну а дальше я уже сам эти значения обработаю....

**как отправить эти данные?**

Comment: такое можно еще организовать на Ангуляре JS. Яркий пример [ChangeInfo.ru](http://ChangeInfo.ru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ прост: если есть аналог, то изучай досконально, как он работает.

В данном случае надо изучить, что происходит при кликах по ссылкам в таблице выбора валют. И вариант реализации, применённый на сайте, не самый сложный - в таблице по клику на ссылки вызывается функция clk из javascript

```
<table>
   <tr id="ti1"><td class="lc" id="dlc1"><a href="http://www.bestchange.ru/wmz-to-wme.html" id="alc1" onclick="return clk(1, 'lc')" class="">WMZ</a></td><td class="rc" id="drc1"><a href="http://www.bestchange.ru/yandex-money-to-wmz.html" id="arc1" onclick="return clk(1, 'rc')" class="">WMZ</a></td></tr>
<tr id="ti2" class="alt"><td class="lc" id="dlc2"><a href="http://www.bestchange.ru/wmr-to-wme.html" id="alc2" onclick="return clk(2, 'lc')" class="">WMR</a></td><td class="rc" id="drc2"><a href="http://www.bestchange.ru/yandex-money-to-wmr.html" id="arc2" onclick="return clk(2, 'rc')" class="">WMR</a></td></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
// варианты вызова
//    clk(1, 'lc')   - "откуда"
//    clk(2, 'rc')   - "куда"
function clk(id, direct, nofollow) {
    // тут волшебство: найти код валюты "откуда", кода валюты "куда", сделать запрос через AJAX с курсами разных обменников (это где-то на одном сервере собирается), затем обновить таблицу курсов
}
</script>
```

Я бы всё это сделал на knockout.js или angular.js на крайний случай - на jquery

- Интерактивный курс по javascript тут: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript и https://www.codeschool.com/paths/javascript#javascript
- По нокауту учебник здесь: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/
- По ангуляру здесь: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js  и http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-advanced-en-2hJ3J/0/1
- По jquery здесь: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery и ещё  http://try.jquery.com/

Comment: Обращайся, если нужна помощь

Comment: спасибо за ссылки на инфу, но на то чтобы разобратся во всем уйдет много времени, а скрипт нужен как можно быстрее... ((( дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Сначала просишь информацию "как сделать", а потом "сделайте". Чтобы сделать такое, надо знать как минимум javascript и ajax. Можно сделать всё по старинке на server-side, если с javascript не получается.